# How to post a file into my s3 url in java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3

I'm trying to practice using AWS more and I'm at a point where I can generate a S3 bucket URL. Now that I have that set up I'm trying to put a document (file) into that URL. Is there any useful documentation or things I should know when I try to do that? I can't seem to find anything on the web for Java users. (maybe I'm just bad at searching idk). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is AWS SDK for Java provided by Amazon

[AWS SDK For Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/)

[Example work with S3](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/src/samples/AmazonS3)

Answer (score 0):

AWS example of loading file to s3:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#upload-object

and you would need a token to access you account resources from a java client more info here : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-access-key/